# Opinion on best way to create the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, mootools

Hey guys I need your advice and ideas on this. I have a menu that looks sort of like this

```
<span class="options">Option 1</span>
<div class="more">More</div>
<span class="options">Option 1</span>
    <div class="more">More</div>
<span class="options">Option 1</span>
    <div class="more">
         <div id="slider" class="slider">
              <div id="knob" class="knob"></div>
              </div>
      </div>
<span class="options">Option 1</span>
    <div class="more">More</div>
<span class="options">Option 1</span>
    <div class="more">More</div>
```

The `.more` is hidden and when the user clicks any of the `.options` spans it will place the HTML into a "popup" I made. Here is quick JS I did

```
$(function() {
   $('.options').click(function() {
      var theHTML = $(this).next('.more').html();
        $('.popup').html(theHTML);
     });
```

And well this isn't the way I want since when I add more detail to it (the .more doesn't say more in them) such as the MooTools Drag/Slider it doesn't work because I am duplicating the html. I also tried APPEND and after I APPEND it the whole thing goes array... Any ideas on what I should do? If you need a better example please let me know...

Comment: It would be better if you can show it in fiddle?

Comment: A little hard but I will try my best. give me one minute

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand very well, but maybe you would use jQuery's delegate. http://api.jquery.com/on/ smthng like: $(document).on('click','.options',function()...

Comment: Here is fiddle... http://jsbin.com/owesog/1/edit   I used the on function too and didn't work

Comment: Maybe, that's what you need http://jsbin.com/owesog/3/edit I've use `.clone(true)`. If I understand right, that will helps

Comment: No `.clone()` didn't work either. please see http://jsbin.com/owesog/4/edit as I made a mistake with the slider code

Comment: @EasyBB why are using mootools and jquery together? just curious, you can combine the libraries but do **you** need to?

Comment: MooTools for the slider, jQuery/Vanilla for the rest of the items.

Answer (score 1):

It did not work because you appended new HTML after whole Jquery plugins have done loaded and attached. You should have to rebind/reattach the plugin that you want.